# Smallest way to call a function

Tags: javascript, short

First, I was calling my functions like this:

```
var a=1;
a=foo(a,2);
```

Then I discovered `prototype` and called my functions like this:

```
var a=1;
a=a.foo(2);
```

And smaller if it's for arrays or objects:

```
var a=[1,2,3];
a.foo(2);
```

Is there a way to call functions like this: `a(2)` or `a[2]` with a hack or something?

Comment: One question... why... why... why?

Comment: Just for fun or just to learn... :)

Comment: Making code as small/short as possible inhibits readability/maintainability. If you're worried about your payload in a production environment, look into using a minifier instead such as http://www.minifyjavascript.com/

Comment: What exactly do you think is going on here? You are calling the functions in exactly the same way each time. The only thing that changes is the object that has a property with a function value (and also the fact that in the first case you need to pass in explicitly a parameter that's passed in as `this` in the latter ones, but that's not the point of your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this;

```
var a=[1,2,3];
var m = "reallyLongMethodName";
a[m](2);
```

Which would call `a.reallyLongMethodName(2)` using [square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html).

Things like this *is* possible in JavaScript:

```
var a=[1,2,3];
var c = a.foo;
c(2);
```

**But**, this won't work in your case as the `this` reference inside `c` would no longer be the array.

You could fix this using `call()` or [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply);

```
c.call(a, 2);
```

But that's probably too long for your liking.

You could also create a wrapper function;

```
function c(ar, val) {
    ar.foo(val);
}

c(a, 2);
```

... but again, that's probably too long for your liking ;).

So all in all, what you've got is as short as it'll be... **Congratulations. You've made your code as unreadable as possible.**

Comment: assigning functions to variables will not work in some browsers (IE9 comes to mind)

Comment: @user1365010: I don't understand what you're trying to say?

Comment: @jbabey: That can't be true? That's quite fundamental to JavaScript.. have you got an example!? :O.

Comment: @Matt i have not actually tested it, i just read about it on [MSDN IE9 changelog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622930.aspx). You essentially lose the context object `a` when you assign `a.foo` to `c`. Calling `c(2)` then looks for the property `c` on the global object instead of `a`, which fails.

Comment: @jbabey: It works that way in every browser, it's even explained in the answer.

Comment: Oi people see @Esailija's responce .. better solution !

Comment: @Abhishek: You can change the accepted answer if you find that one more useful.

Answer (score 4):

```
Array.prototype.foo = function(index) {
    return this[index];
};

var a=[1,2,3];

a = a.foo.call.bind(a.foo, a);


a(2); //3; 
a(1); //2
a(0); //1
```